# G++ stops working when used in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I'm currently trying to use a makefile to automate my build process which I am still new to. When I run the g++ command:

`g++ -I includes -L lib -lSDL2_test -lSDL2 -lSDL2main main.o -o main.exe`

from the following makefile:

```
main: main.o
    g++ -I includes -L lib -lSDL2_test -lSDL2 -lSDL2main main.o -o main.exe

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
```

I get `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`

However when running the same g++ command from the same directory as the makefile everything compiles correctly and I don't get the error. So how do I fix this?

EDIT:

I've done some testing and found out the problem with the makefile is that the `-I includes` g++ flag is not enabling the main.o file to find `SDL.H`, hopefully that helps to narrow down the problem.

Comment: What do you get before that?

Comment: @immibis `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_Delay", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in main.o`

Comment: Are you sure that is the command `make` is running?

Comment: @immibis I'm pretty much certain.

Comment: Is that the command it prints out when you run `make`?

Comment: @immibis It is.

Comment: Unrelated but... you have the `-I includes` flags in the wrong rule.  Those flags affect the preprocessor  and should be in the `main.o: main.cpp` rule rather than `main: main.o`.

Comment: @G.M. thanks for the tip, I'm still getting used to makefiles.

Comment: @JustGameDev `-I` flags never belong to the linking, but to the compilation proper phase, no matter whether this is done from a makefile or command line.

Comment: I would advise you to take a look at CMake. There is no reason to make your own Makefile. Besides, CMake will generate a much better one for you.

Comment: @xorz57 will do, thanks!

Comment: Why are you having `main` as a target when you want to compile `main.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

@G.M's comment isn't unrelated - it's the correct answer to the problem.  The include files are needed during the compile stage (the `main.o: main.cpp` rule), **NOT** during the link stage (i.e. the `main: main.o` rule.)

Move the `-I includes` flag to the second rule, and try again.